# Byte string spanning more than one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, literals, string-literals

I need to parse byte string which spans more than one line in the source code. Like this

```
self.file.write(b'#compdef %s\n\n'
                    '_arguments -s -A "-*" \\\n' % (self.cmdName,))
```

this line throws the following exception

```
builtins.SyntaxError: cannot mix bytes and nonbytes literals
```

which can be fixed in the following way

```
self.file.write(b'#compdef %s\n\n\'\'_arguments -s -A "-*" \\\n' % (self.cmdName,))
```

Notice the backslashes after `\n`. but this fix does the follow the project rules of less than 79 characters per line.

How do I fix this?

The code works fine on Python 2 but fails on Python 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are fine to use multiple string literals, but they need to be of the same *type*. You are missing the `b` prefix on the second line:

```
self.file.write(b'#compdef %s\n\n'
                b'_arguments -s -A "-*" \\\n' % (self.cmdName,))
```

Only when using string literals of the same type will the python parser merge these into one longer `bytes` string object.

It worked on Python 2 because the `b` prefix is a no-op; `b'..'` and `'..'` produce the same type of object. The `b` prefix only exists in Python 2 to make it easier to write code for both Python 2 and 3 in the same codebase (polyglot).