# Convert multiline bytestring, typed as string type to proper string

Tags: python, python-3.x

My log files have some multiline bytestring in them, like

[2019-05-25 19:16:31] b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'

After I try to extract the original multiline string, how do I convert that to a real string
using Python 3?

As a simplified example, after reading the log file and stripping the time, I end up with a variable that has the type str and has the b' prefix, as a string.

```
# note: b'' is inside the str (taken from log)
tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
# convert here  
print(tmp)
```

I'm looking for a way to tell python that the content needs to get decoded. But str doesn't allow decoding.

The result I'd like to see from the print command is

```
logstring
more log
```

UPDATE: The "eval" function will produce this result, but this would execute the code, so it's not safe.

```
# note: b'' is inside the str (taken from log)
tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
tmp = eval(tmp) 
print(tmp)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326297/byte-string-spanning-more-than-one-line

Comment: Thanks Mike, but that doesn't help. The imported text is in string format, because the "b" is part of the log file. The question you linked to doesn't address this problem

Comment: You should fix whatever is generating this. Using `eval` is the most straightforward way of hacking a solution to this problem. If safety is an issue then use `import ast; ast.literal_eval` for safely evaluating the string representing the bytes literal, then decode it, but again, *fix the source of this issue*.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Regarding fixing the source, I'm parsing (existing) log files to extract data so fixing the source is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
r = re.compile(r"b'(.+)'", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
result = r.sub(r"\1", tmp)
print(result) # logstring\r\n\r\nmore log
```

You could use this for the entire file or line by line but you may need to slightly change this code to meet your needs.

**- Edit -**
If you want to remove duplicate newlines (as your desired output shows) you can do it like this:

```
import re
tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
binary_regex = re.compile(r"b'(.+)'", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
newline_regex = re.compile(r"(\r\n)+", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
# Make sure to do the compiles outside of any loops you have
result = binary_regex.sub(r"\1", tmp) # Remove the b''
result = newline_regex.sub(r"\r\n", result) # Remove duplicate new lines
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
logstring
more log
```

Comment: `r = re.compile(r"b'(.+)'", re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @Mike thank you. I don't have much practice with regex.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can lock down the eval function so that it can't run functions and python builtins. You do this by passing a dictionary of allowed global and local functions.
By mapping all builtins to None you can block the execution of regular python commands. With that in place, using eval to evaluate the string content is safe.

Source [this article](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html)

```
# note: b'' is inside the str (taken from log)
tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
tmp = eval(tmp, {'__builtins__': None}, {}) 
print(tmp)
```

And in the comments above @juanpa.arrivillaga offered another solution, that also solves the eval security problem:

```
import ast

tmp =  "b'logstring\r\n\r\nmore log'"
tmp = ast.literal_eval(tmp) 
print(tmp)
```